# Filtrate PSCustomObject values based on a field condition

Tags: powershell, csv, ssl

Hello I have the following script that allows me to get certificate details and store them in a `CSV` file.I want to exclude some certificate informations from appearing into the `CSV` file which are certificates having more then 3650 days remaining before expiry

Here is my script

```
$StartDate = Get-Date
$CertPath = 'Cert:\LocalMachine\'
$CertsDetail = Get-ChildItem -Path $CertPath -Recurse | 
Where-Object { $_.PsIsContainer -ne $true } | ForEach-Object {                               
$DaysLeft = (New-TimeSpan -Start $StartDate -End $_.NotAfter).Days
if ($DaysLeft -lt 1) {
    $Under30 = $true
    $Expired = $true
    $Text = "The Certificate is expired"
}
elseif ($DaysLeft -lt 30) {
    $Under30 = $true
    $Expired = $false
    $Text = "The Certificate is but valid about to expire"
}
else {
    $Under30 = $false
    $Expired = $false
    $Text = "The Certificate is still valid and not going soon to expire"
}
    $FinalDate = get-date $_.NotAfter -Format 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm'

[PSCustomObject]@{
    Text = $Text
    Subject = $_.Subject
    ExpireDate = $FinalDate
    DaysRemaining = $DaysLeft
    Under30Days = $Under30
    Expired = $Expired
}
}
 $CertsDetail | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path'C:\SECnology\Data\Utilities\Certificate_State.csv'
```

Comment: Did you mean 365 days?

Comment: no i mean more then 10 years

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have a field in your object for days remaining, so its a simple case of using `Where-Object` on your `$CertsDetail` collection to filter out the results you don't want:

```
$CertsDetail | Where-Object { $_.DaysRemaining -lt 3650 } | Export-CSV ...
```